# Securing user input through forms PHP

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I am making my own social media network for a project at college. One hurdle I have come across is secure forms.

I am making an option for one user to send a friend request to another user, which I can code. But that tricky part is making it secure. If I were to just use xxxxxx/profile.php?id=2&action=sendfr then people could be sent that link and made to send them a friend request.

If I sent action=sendfr as POST data then a spoofer could make a form on a website to do the same.

One method I am considering is sending some sort of AuthKey in POST data that is sent to the client for these purposes.

Could anyone please recommend the best option for making user actions secure?

Comment: CSRF will possibly help here, or secure cookie perhaps

Comment: The only cookie I use is PHPSESSID, My consideration is when the page loads having a token sent to the user via javascript variable that can be used in POST forms to authenticate actions.

Comment: You using a framework?

Comment: Look into CSRF tokens as suggested by Andy.

Comment: Thank you, yes that I what I am research now

Comment: No Andy, I hardcode all my php, html and css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to avoid is a [Cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). [There several ways to avoid them](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#CSRF_Specific_Defense) but the most popular is to generate a random token in the server and send it with every page that can make changes in persistent data. Then when the user sends a request back it must include the token so the server can verify that the tokens match. In this case the tokens must be random and different in every request. You would find more details and techniques in the OWASP page linked above.

Comment: I have just make it so when a session starts (user logs in); for that php session the user is given a token that is stored in $_SESSION. This token is echoed into forms which relay it back to the server via POST.

Comment: As long as your CSRF token is not the same as the session token you should be OK